# Customizing Web Parts - Hiding property in edit mode?

Tags: web-part

Update:

```
private string _catalogIconImageUrl = "http://hostname/images/favicon.ico";

 [WebBrowsableAttribute(false),
    Category("HIDDEN"),
    Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User),
    WebDisplayName("Catalog Icon Image url"),
    WebDescription("Something")]
    public string CatalogIconImageUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return _catalogIconImageUrl;
        }
        set
        {
            _catalogIconImageUrl = value;
        }
    }
```

with the above code, it does not show the image and also when i click on edit the webpart i still able to see the catalogIconImageUrl prop in edit mode

**Update end**

I've declared the property CatalogIconImageURL in the `.Webpart` file as follows:-

```
</property>    
<property name="CatalogIconImageUrl" type="string">images/company/companylogo.jpg</property>    //sample path...
</properties>
```

if I click on the Advanced Web Part Gallery as shown below in the screen shot, i able to see that property in `editable` so my question is, is there a way i can hide this property when user edit the web part? `"Catalog Icon Image URL"`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The attribute should be `WebBrowsable(false)` not `WebBrowsableAttribute(false)`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webbrowsableattribute(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: Not correct. `[WebBrowsable(false)]` and `[WebBrowsableAttribute(false)]` are both legal and equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

So is this a custom webpart that you coded?  If so, you can change the property attributes in the code (not .webpart file):

```
   [WebBrowsableAttribute(false),
    Category("HIDDEN"),
    Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User),
    WebDisplayName("Catalog Icon Image url"),
    WebDescription("Something")]
    public string CatalogIconImageUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return _catalogIconImageUrl;
        }
        set
        {
            _catalogIconImageUrl = value;
        }
    }
```

The one that will hide it when they click edit is the WebBrowseableAttribute(false), the other code is there just to help you with context.

Comment: still showing when i edit the webpart

Comment: Can you post a portion of your C# code?  Also, if you change the category, display name, or description, does it change it in edit mode as well?

Comment: i have updated my question...